# C++ vector [] operator throws error while at() works

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class A that contains a vector and a function that returns a pointer to this vector like this.

```
std::vector<ALuint> * SoundComponent::getSource()
{
    return &m_Sources;
}
```

I have another class B that need to modify the values in the vector of class A by calling the `getSource()` function. So I acquire the pointer to the vector by doing this.

```
std::vector<ALuint> * sources = m_pSoundComponent[i]->getSource();
```

And `m_pSoundComponent` is an array of class A. Now let`s say for example I want to add 1 to the entries in the vector. For some reason`operator []`gives me an error but`at` works just fine. So here are 3 things that I tried, and two of them work, but I want to know why the first one is wrong.

```
sources[0] += 1; //Does not work
sources[0][0] += 1; //Works ? Not sure why it became a 2D vector.
sources->at(0) += 1; //works
```

I heard that `at()` r is much slower than `operator []`, so I am trying to use the `operator []`, but I am not sure why it is a 2D vector now.

Also, in class A, I can just use `sources[0]` with no errors but `sources[0][0]` gives me an error.

Comment: `sources` is a pointer, not a vector.

Comment: You need to find a better C++ teacher/lesson that properly teaches you *references*.

Comment: change it to `(*sources)[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sources` is defined as a `std::vector<ALuint> *`.  This means that `sources[0]` gives you the vector, it does not access the element in the vector.  It is the same as `(*sources)`.  So `sources[0] += 1` doesn't make sense as you are trying to add `1` to a vector, not a vector element.

With `sources[0][0]` you get the vector and then access the 0th element of the vector.  This is the same as `(*sources)[0]`.

`sources->at(0)` does the same thing.  `->` is the member access operator for pointers so it is the same as `(*sources).at(0)`

---

All of this can be avoided though if you return a reference instead of a pointer.  You can change

```
std::vector<ALuint> * SoundComponent::getSource()
{
    return &m_Sources;
}
```

to

```
std::vector<ALuint>& SoundComponent::getSource()
{
    return m_Sources;
}
```

and then that allows you to use

```
std::vector<ALuint>& sources = m_pSoundComponent[i]->getSource();
```

Which allows you to use `sources` like you normally would.

Comment: Oh god, I can`t believe I forgot how the pointers and references work.This is what happen when I stop coding in C++ for years and code in Python :). Thank you very much.